# Compiling PHP Into Standalone Executable (Faster?)

Tags: php, compiler-construction, compilation

I have a PHP script I'd like to compile into a standalone command-line executable for running on Linux.

Is this realistic? Are there compilers for this?

I know that there are PHP compilers around, but my question is oriented more to whether it is of advantage, and which is the best compiler to use.

Will it be faster or slower than running it through PHP? If it would speed up my script then that would be great, since it does a lot of processing (lots of loops and math) and takes an hour to run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/) compiles to C++, not C, and that the process is quite easy. FaceBook has applied it to vast amounts of code.

I'm not sure you get a .exe, but OP only wants "faster". He might get quite a good speedup; HipHop compiled-code averages only a factor of 2 or so faster, but that's because much of PHP execution is really library calls. He might get pretty good speedup on his computation part, if the HipHop compiler can figure out what the data types are in the computation code.  He might have to modify his code somewhat to make this clear to the HipHop compiler, by not using his computation varaibles for anything but computation but that should be only a minor source code change.  I'd expect the HipHop site to contain hints about what to do to speed up HipHop compiled code along these lines.

All of this is educated guess based on what I understand and not actual experience. YMMV.

Comment: Yeah, I write pretty clean PHP, apart from doing calculations on unset variables - but that can be fixed.

Comment: Unsetting a variable and then using it only for numeric arithmetic may be one of the things that helps the compiler.

Comment: I don't use different types in the same variable, but I'm doing a lot of processing where $var[1] and $var[3] may be set, but $var[2] is unset because it's value is 0 so I never bothered to set it, and PHP just treats this as if it is value 0, which is what I want. Would this be an issue with HipHop?

Comment: Dunno... you're out of my experience area.  If HipHop indeed produces C++ arrays, you would do well IMHO to make sure all the slots were filled with a number value.  That's won't hurt your vanilla PHP code.  However,  I'm operating as an armchair expert here, but I have very good compiler background so my guesses are arguably educated.  Now you get to do the reading I didn't do :-}

Comment: Just want to report back that it took me 3 solid days to install Hiphop, but once I got it working it has reduced the time for my script by half, and the RAM usage by 25%. Very impressed! It's like magic!

Comment: So much for "the process is quite easy" :-} Have you looked at the generated C++ to see if the code is reasonably efficient?  That might give you some clues as to how you bend the PHP code to make it easier for HipHop to help you. I would have expected better performance than that on computational stuff.

Comment: HipHop varies in executable speed. I have PHP code that gets executed faster via PHP-CLI than HipHop generated binary does. Also, there's `SplFixedArray` data structure that already reduces memory footprint of arrays by roughly 40% and there's also `Judy` which is even more memory efficient (but you trade processing time req. to fill the Judy array). From what I've seen trough my testing, HipHop isn't **that** fascinating. It mostly speeds up badly optimized PHP code and does virtually nothing on already optimal PHP code.

Comment: @N.B.: "Already optimal PHP code"? What on earth is that? Good compilers do things that are hard or impossible for programmers to code "efficiently" on the target architectures.  I was surprised by Alastair's remark that he only got 25% on computationally-intense code; modern CPUs can do arithmetic at truly astonishing rates, so I conclude HipHop is somehow not doing a great job, just one that is better than native PHP.  You're telling me that PHP uses awful data structures for arrays and that may be the trouble. (Judy? That's the HP optimized-to-heck package? Is that integrated into PHP?)

Comment: I use PHP for various importing jobs and queues that work with arrays a lot (CLI). That's why I usually try to make it as low in memory footprint as possible with PHP's functions (not much wiggling room there). I had a script that transforms dates from random date formats to MySQL's `datetime` one (using `DateTime` class). For a few mil. entries, native PHP was 2x faster compared to the binary I got from HipHop. However, the binary used less memory, unless I used HP's `Judy`. Judy is available as extension for PHP. I'll test new PHP 5.4 against HipHop soon and I'll post results.

Answer (score 0):

Well, compiling itself will add very little if your script runs for hours.
The best solution would be to use another language, C seems woud be the best choice.

you can try to translate your PHP to C using hiphop compiler but it is not the task I'd call easy

Comment: How does he use C for a PHP application?  I didn't understand what you meant.